# Entity Framework migration fails trying to insert NULL into CreatedOn

Tags: entity-framework-4, migration

I'm trying to update my database on a development server (it all worked fine on my local machine) using Entity Framework and Code First Migrations. I used the command `update-database -Script -SourceMigration:201305161422570_AddedWidgets` to generate the necessary script. When I ran this script in SQL Management Studio (2008R2) on my server, I get an error every time the script tries to write to the __MigrationHistory table. The exact error is:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedOn', table 'master.dbo.__MigrationHistory'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I've never encountered this error before, but I find it very odd because my __MigrationHistory table doesn't have a column `CreatedOn`, nor am I trying to put anything into a column named that. Here is one of my insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO [__MigrationHistory] ([MigrationId], [Model], [ProductVersion]) VALUES ('201306031825584_AddedTitleToSocialLevel', 0x1F8B0800000000000400EDBDDD92...0, '5.0.0.net45')
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Sounds to me like a versioning issue, your code is running a different ver to that which created the migrations table. I would probably try EF 4.3 (rather than 5) and see if it fixes the problem. Perhaps then you can isolate it and work out if thats the root cause.

Comment: Yep, it was definitely a versioning issue in my case - I had previously (accidentally) upgraded to the EF6 beta, ran it, then downgraded back to 5.0 stable. Worked at the time, but that was clearly the source of this error. Wiped that db and had EF recreate it, it worked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at the error and the suggestion from wagregg, I realized that the generated script was looking for my __MigrationHistory table in `master.dbo.MigrationHistory`, but that's not actually where it is.

I changed each of these references from `[__MigrationHistory]` to `[EnterpriseWebDB].[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error is certainly complaining that in the database "master" there is a table "__MigrationHistory" that definitely has a non nullable column "CreatedOn" that is not being set when you are inserting that row.  You should double check the schema of the Dev server's DB.